# Jmeter variables value is not getting set after each loop

Tags: jmeter

I am using the loop controller to loop an array & give HTTP request for each value. But in some cases, variable values are set with current value from the array

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case the array simply doesn't have the variable matching the current loop index, double check the [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which are in scope for each loop using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination.

I cannot reproduce your issue using the following simple setup:

1. JMeter Variables defined:

   [image]
2. The variables referenced using __V() and [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) functions combination like:

   ```
   ${__V(var_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)})}
   ```

   [image]

   See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/) for the clarification of the syntax used.

If you just need to iterate JMeter Variables it might be easier to go for the [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller):

[image]

[image]